# Boyer moore algorithm - count all matching substrings

Tags: python, boyer-moore

I am implementing the boyer moore algorithm in python, and i need to count how many times a substring appears in a string.

My string is stored in a vector:

```
string = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'B']
```

The needle is also a vector:

```
needle = ['B', 'B']
```

My problem is:

The algorithm as i have implemented just returns the index where the needle appears for the first time.
In the example above, it returns `1`, but, as i said before, i need to count every time whether the needle is appearing within the array, and expect it to  return 2;

**Examples and expected return**

**1**

```
haystack = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'B']
needle = ['B', 'B'] 
expected return = 2
```

**2**

```
haystack = ['A', 'F', 'T', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'T', 'a', 'F', 'T']
needles = ['F', 'T']
expected return = 3
```

**My code** i
In the `search` function, i have tried to change the `return i` (the index), with `counter += 1`, to count the matching needles, but, if i do it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "booyer-moore.py", line 103, in <module>
    main(files)
  File "booyer-moore.py", line 98, in main
    index = search(haystack, needle)
  File "booyer-moore.py", line 18, in search
    i += max(offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j], character_table.get(haystack[i]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
def search(haystack, needle):
    counter = 0
    if len(needle) == 0:
        return 0
    character_table = createCharacterTable(needle)
    offset_table = createOffsetTable(needle)

    i = len(needle) - 1

    while i < len(haystack):
        j = len(needle) - 1
        while needle[j] == haystack[i]:
            if j == 0:
                return i
                # counter += 1
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        i += max(offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j], character_table.get(haystack[i]))
    return counter


def createCharacterTable(needle):
    table = {}
    for i in range(len(needle) - 1):
        table[needle[i]] = len(needle) - 1 - i
    return table


def createOffsetTable(needle):
    table = []
    lastPrefixPosition = len(needle)
    for i in reversed(range(len(needle))):
        if isPrefix(needle, i + 1):
            lastPrefixPosition = i + 1
        table.append(lastPrefixPosition - i + len(needle) + 1)
    for i in range(len(needle) - 1):
        slen = suffixLength(needle, i)
        table[slen] = len(needle) - 1 - i + slen
    return table


def isPrefix(needle, position):
    j = 0
    for i in range(position, len(needle)):
        if needle[i] != needle[j]:
            return False
        j += 1
    return True


def suffixLength(needle, position):
    length = 0
    j = len(needle) - 1
    for i in reversed(range(position + 1)):
        if needle[i] == needle[j]:
            length += 1
        else:
            break
        j -= 1
    return length
```

Answer (score 2):

Have found a couple of errors which I have rectified in your solution.

```
def search(haystack, needle):
    if len(needle) == 0:
        return 0
    character_table = createCharacterTable(needle)
    offset_table = createOffsetTable(needle)
    i = len(needle) - 1
    while i < len(haystack):
        j = len(needle) - 1
        while needle[j] == haystack[i]:
            if j == 0:
                yield i
                break
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        if(character_table.get(haystack[i])):
            i += max(character_table.get(haystack[i]),offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j])
        else:
            i += offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j]

haystack = ['A', 'F', 'T', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'T', 'a', 'F', 'T']
needle = ['F', 'T']
generator=search(haystack,needle)
for i in generator:
    print("Result: "+str(i))
```

The problem of returning multiple solutions can be fixed by using a generator i.e. **yielding** the values instead of returning them.

Added a check to your character_table.get(haystack[i]) as I kept getting this error as your values in your character_table dictionary were non-existent in case of a mismatch.

```
i += max(character_table.get(haystack[i]),offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j])

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Results from this

```
Result: 1
Result: 5
```

Now I printed your offsetTable which gave me [1, 5] which does not look right to me. Printing the values of i and j during execution I got:

```
{'F': 1} [1, 5]
j is 1
i is 2
Result: 1
j is 0
i is 6
Result: 5
j is 0
i is 10
```

So there is a skip between index 6 and 10. Could you explain the logic of your offset table? I will update this answer if I can figure out any error in the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits that `max` afterward, but I guess you should reset `i`to the value it had before inner while started (if your needle size is 2 then that `i -= 1` occured once), update counter and then break:

```
        if j == 0:
            i += len(needle) - 1
            counter += 1
            break
        i -= 1
        j -= 1
```

Comment: I tried it with this haystack: `haystack = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']`
and this needle:  `needle = ['B', 'B']`, and

it gives me `2` as answer

Comment: Dunno, really, I guess you should react to @Axxelerated answer and find the way to solve your problem.